# Initializing new columns in pd.pivot_table using existing columns within pd.pivot_table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have table imported into python using pd.read_csv that looks as follows

[image: dataset]

I need to perform 3 activities on this table as follows

1. Calculate the number of free apps and paid apps in each genre using group by.

I wrote following code to get the desired output `

df.groupby(['prime_genre','Subscription'])[['id']].count()`

Output:

[image: code1_output]

2. Convert the result from 1 into a dataframe having the columns as prime_genre, free, paid and the rows having the count of each

I wrote the following code to get the desired output

df1 = df.groupby(['prime_genre','Subscription'])['id'].count().reset_index()
df1.pivot_table(index='prime_genre', columns='Subscription', values='id', aggfunc='sum')

Output:

[image: code2_output]

3. Now I need to initialize a column 'Total' that captures the sum of 'free app' and 'paid app' within the pivot table itself
4. I also I need to initialize two more columns perc_free and perc_paid that displays the percentage of free apps and paid apps within the pivot table itself

How do I go about 3 & 4?

Comment: Please take a while to read: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: for 3. pass `margins=True` in `pivot_table()`

Comment: @Anurag Dabas will this work for columns? I thought the margins would be for the rows' total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following pivot table named `df2`:

```
subscription  free app  paid app
prime_genre                     
book                66        46
business            20        37
catalogs             9         1
education          132       321
```

You can calculate the total using [`pandas.DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) on the columns (`axis=1`). Then divide `df2` with this total and multiply by 100 to get the percentage. You can add a suffix to the columns with [`pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html). Finally, combine everything with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
total = df2.sum(axis=1)
percent = df2.div(total, axis=0).mul(100).add_suffix(' percent')
df2['Total'] = total
pd.concat([df2, percent], axis=1)
```

output:

```
subscription  free app  paid app  Total  free app percent  paid app percent
prime_genre                                                                
book                66        46    112         58.928571         41.071429
business            20        37     57         35.087719         64.912281
catalogs             9         1     10         90.000000         10.000000
education          132       321    453         29.139073         70.860927
```

Here is a variant to get the `perc_free` / `perc_paid` names:

```
total = df2.sum(axis=1)
percent = (df2.div(total, axis=0)
              .mul(100)
              .rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub('(.*)( app)', r'perc_\1',x))
          )
df2['Total'] = total
pd.concat([df2, percent], axis=1)
```

```
subscription  free app  paid app  Total  perc_free  perc_paid
prime_genre                                                  
book                66        46    112  58.928571  41.071429
business            20        37     57  35.087719  64.912281
catalogs             9         1     10  90.000000  10.000000
education          132       321    453  29.139073  70.860927
```

Comment: If I have to rename 'free app percent' as 'perc_free' and 'paid app percent' as 'perc_paid'. Then what changes shall I make?

Comment: Please read the latest version of the answer. I provided this use case.